# App dir not showing on device file browser

Tags: android

I am busy developing an Android app and regularly run it on a device for testing purposes. The app saves some files and images to the app file directory. However, when I open my file browser "Android File Transfer" on my mac, I see the directories for all other apps on the device, but not my own. How can I browse the files created by my app on the device?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see your app files on a real running device, you probably want to store them in the external files area, which is probably what you are seeing in your file transfer window. see Context.getExternalFilesDir(). Remember that other apps can see them as well..

Answer (score 0):

If you have an *un-rooted* device, In my experience you would have hidden folders. But if it is rooted then you can mount all of the dir(s) R/W and it will reveal lots of stuff.

On the other hand I would use an app called "ES File explorer", it is completely free.

By the way which directory are you using? There are more than one...

Comment: If you're testing an app for general release, you probably won't want to be testing on a rooted phone.

Comment: Yes but you couldn't access the app directories to check for the files. If it is rooted, you don't have to give root permissions to any of the apps. So the phone will act if it was unrooted (to the app(s).